# WiFi Connection Problem!

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I have an an android phone. The problem is that when I connect my phone, which is android Jelly Bean, to my Wi-Fi connection it works and the internet connection doesn't have any issues.

However, when I open my PC the phone loses the connection and no internet is established on the phone, while it works at the same time, very good on the PC and any other phone connected on the Wi-Fi. I hope you help me find the cause.

I tried to find the issue but I couldn't!
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you checked if there if any IP conflicts between your phone and any of the other devices which are connecting to the wi-fi.

Comment: Are you using DHCP? If not and if you can, do so. DHCP should take care of things like @xavier_fakerat mentioned, however when using static IPs and the PC and phone tries to use the same this can cause conflicts. In addition, check the MAC addresses of both devices. It's highly unlikely that they are the same, but you never know.

Comment: @confetti I checked the phone and it uses DHCP, but I tried to stop the antivirus for an hour and it worked. I use Avast, and when I susbended its work for a while the wifi connection works as it should be. So, should I remove the antivirus app or not? As if I removed it, the PC won't be safe!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have allowed only one device to be connected at a time in your `WIFI`modem, kindly check that there is an option in your modem of connected devices in which you have selected 1, change it to as maximum as you can and then try